# How do I delegate derived class method to protocol method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance

I am very new to Objective C. Please excuse me if you find my question very naive. I tried searching on web, but due to lack of good context, search results don't seem to fit my requirement.

I have a method `foo` declared in protocol `P`. `interface` Derived inherit from `P` and provide implementation of `foo`. I have another `interface` `AnotherDerived` which inherit from protocol `P`. I want to delegate call from method of `AnotherDerived` to `foo` so that Derived method gets invoked.

```
@protocol P <NSObject>
@required

- (NSString *)foo;

@end

@interface Derived: NSObject <P>
- (NSString *)foo
{
    return _foo;
}
@end

@interface AnotherDerived: NSObject <P>
- (NSString *)foo
{
    return [super foo];  <----------------- I need something like this. It should call method of Derived
}
@end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you make your question a bit less abstract? I think the I and the P and the foo are hard to follow. Could you make a more concrete explanation?

Comment: I am sorry for the discomfort. I am adding more details.

Comment: to call [super foo] your  AnotherDerived should be inheritated from  Derived

Comment: @MikeAlter: I know this is wrong. Is there any way to achieve what I want to do?

Comment: You can't do that unless `AnotherDerived` inherits from `Derived`. Simply because two classes implement the same protocol, doesn't mean that there is some relationship between those two classes.

Comment: @Paulw11: Please correct me I am mistaken. I read about sister delagation in C++ sometime back. Not sure if that come in handy here.

Comment: You can see an example of that here http://qa.geeksforgeeks.org/569/what-is-sister-delegation-and-how-it-is-implemented Note that in that case both B and C inherit from a common ancestor, A, and there is a class, D, that is composed of B and C. This is not the situation you have described in your question

Comment: My bad memory. This answer was written by me 2 years back. Rumplestiltskin was my handle name. Thanks @Paulw11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because two classes implement the same protocol, doesn't mean that there is some relationship between those two classes. The `foo` method in `AnotherDerived` has no knowledge that there is some other class, `Derived`, that also implements `foo`.

You could allocate an instance of `Derived` explicitly in `AnotherDerived`'s `foo` and use that:

```
@interface AnotherDerived: NSObject <P>
- (NSString *)foo
{
    Derived *d = [Derived new];
    return [d foo];
}
@end
```

Or you could potentially declare `foo` as a class method:

```
@protocol P <NSObject>
@required

+ (NSString *)foo;

@end

@interface Derived: NSObject <P>
+ (NSString *)foo
{
    return _foo;
}
@end
```

But you would still need to explicitly invoke `foo` from `Derived`

```
@interface AnotherDerived: NSObject <P>
+ (NSString *)foo
{
    return [Derived foo];
}
@end
```

Finally, you could make `AnotherDerived` inherit from `Derived` as others have pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, your `Derived` implements `P`, and your `AnotherDerived` is supposed to call `foo` implemented in `Derived`? You need to make `AnotherDerived` inherit from `Derived`:

```
@interface AnotherDerived: Derived
- (NSString *)foo
{
    return [super foo];
}
```

No need to make `AnotherDerived` implement `P`, because `Derived` already does that.